# New gtag google analytics add url _gl manually

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I'm trying to add to URL the value of _gl in order to apply cross-domain.

Currently, I tried these options:

```
const decorateUrl = (urlString: string) => {
    var ga = window.dataLayer;
    var tracker;
    if (ga && typeof ga.getAll === 'function') {
      tracker = ga.getAll()[0]; // Uses the first tracker created on the page
      urlString = (new window.gaplugins.Linker(tracker)).decorate(urlString);
    }
    
    return urlString;
  }
```

and

```
const decorateURL = (url: string) => {
    let destinationLink = false;
    var ga = window[window['GoogleAnalyticsObject']];
    console.log(ga,'ga test decorate')
    if (ga) {
       let tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
       let linker = new window.gaplugins.Linker(tracker);
       destinationLink = linker.decorate(url);
    }

    return (destinationLink ? url + '?' + destinationLink : url);
}
```

but none of these set _gl code to URL.

and I inject in the header this code

```
let gtagLinkScript = destinationWindow.document.createElement("script");
    gtagLinkScript.setAttribute('async', 'true');
    gtagLinkScript.setAttribute('src', `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${ trackingID }`);
```

and

```
let gtagAnotherScript = destinationWindow.document.createElement("script");
    gtagAnotherScript.innerText = `gtag('set', 'linker', {'domains': [\'${crossDomain}\']});gtag(\'config\', \'${ trackingID }\');`;
```

can someone help?

Comment: Can you add the code you used to invoke these functions? Example, element.addEventListener....etc.

Comment: if (!window.gtag) {
                const appGTAGWindowScript = createGTAGWindowScript(
                    window,
                    appConfig.analytics.gtagNewVersionTrackingCode,
                    appConfig.analytics.crossDomain
                );
                operationWindow.document.head.appendChild(appGTAGLinkScript);
                operationWindow.document.head.appendChild(appGTAGWindowScript);
            }

Comment: it's in loader file, that is invoked in header

Comment: I've provided some links to resources which may help in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73066384/manually-generate-ga-linker-parameter-with-gtag-ga4/74680241#answer-74680241

Comment: @CarlosVieira I believe I just answered you question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73066384/manually-generate-ga-linker-parameter-with-gtag-ga4/76123946#76123946

Answer (score 1):

In a GA4 property the recommendation is to pass client_id and session_id over the url: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071811?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmanual-setup